# ASP.NET Timespace between 2 dates and status

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm working with `ASP.NET MVC`.

I have this page:

[image: mypage]

I can add an entry with `Activation` or `Desactivation` and choose the date I want.

**I need help with two things that I even don't know how to start:**

1. I need to validate the new entry to not allow a "Activation" where
   the next entry is an "Activation" too.
2. Create a system that returns me the `timespace` that it was activated and desactivated, in order to create a chronology or a simple graphic with the timespaces and the status.

**Two important things:**

1. I can add any date, even it's past.
2. I can have an Activation as last entry, without any desactivation

TiA!

Comment: so the list you provided would be *invalid* because the first two items are "Activation"?

Comment: @soumer Exact, When I added the `Activation` of 1st row I already had the others Entries. In that case, system should return an alert saying "You can't add a `Activation` when the next entry is an `Activation` too". I want to prevent that situation

Comment: Show some code of what you've tried so far.